# Ng file upload undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a problem with uploading my file. So, I've got:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" ng-click="send()" ng-if="data.try">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Send
</button>
```

Button, which sends my file and informations (text content).

```
  <input type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)"/>
```

File input

And JS code:

```
$scope.send = function(){
    $scope.uploadFiles = function(file, errFiles) {
        $scope.f = file;
        $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
        if (file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'static/css',
                data: {file: file}
            });
            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            });
        }   
        console.log("ASDASD1111111111");
        console.log($scope.f);
    }
    $scope.data.try = false ;
    $scope.sendMailJava();
}
```

And the rest of code, sendMailJava is for next code which sending whole document and informations to JAVA

When I'm trying console.log this file I've got undefined. I don't have really idea what's going on.

Comment: Additionally, look there: http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/0mz6ff9o/135/ . I've got 1:1 code with this example and still nothing. Just undefined. Also i changed code on jsfiddle (button replace with input type file) - works.